# How to make webview content editable in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, contenteditable

I am displaying some information in the webview. I need to make the content editable once the user clicks on the displayed info. The keyboard should appear as well.
I tried to do this by setting contentEditable = true for the webview. It works in iOS, not sure how to do in android.
Please suggest if this can be done or any other way to achieve editing the info?
TIA

Answer (score 5):

```
<div contenteditable=\"true\"> testing < /div>
```

contentEditable = true works for android as well.